# Deleted Ubuntu partion within windows and now computer won't start

Tags: boot

So basically my parents got rather pissy at me for messing with the home computer and putting ubuntu on it as a secondary os. So I was told to unistall it, my friends all use Ubuntu as well and they said they only thing I had to do was to delete the partion Ubuntu was on. So I did.
Now I am greeted with a message on startup which says

```
error: no such partition.

Entering rescue mode

Grub rescue>
```

And I can't boot into windows like I hope I would have been.

My computer came with no windows recovery disk, so I downloaded an ISO and burned it to my USB, due to my laptop not having a disk drive. But the USB won't boot at pc startup so I can't access recovery, unless I have to click something before grub tries to load.

Comment: cool , it's possible to recover. First take a cup of coffee.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need Your Windows boot DVD.  Boot up on that DVD, and select Boot Repair.  This will remove GRUB and restore the windows boot loader.

If you would like to continue using Ubuntu on that machine, make a Live USB stick, and boot up off the stick whenever you would like to use it.  You can even bring use it on other computers and bring all your settings and files with you that way.  This method makes no changes to the host computer, so your parents shouldn't be able to complain.

Edit: Just saw the issue with the windows USB stick.  You have to follow very precise instructions to get Windows installation media to work from a USB stick.  Best done from a working Windows computer.  Please check out this site:

http://bootableusb.net/install-windows-7-usb-drive-easy-way/

Answer (score 0):

Enter the BIOS (usually F12, Delete, F2, or something -- look for "Setup" on the boot screen) or the boot menu. From the BIOS go to the Boot tab and move USB to the top of the list (usually F5 and F6 keys). Then, reboot and it should boot from the USB stick.

Once the USB boots, there should be an option for boot recovery on the first menu. Click that and let it do its thing and you should be left with a bootable computer and Windows only.

Note: After doing this, move HDD back to the top of the list in the BIOS to prevent the computer not booting when certain USB drives are plugged in.